# What's the point of WHERE 1=2 for SELECT INTO table query

Tags: sql-server

If we want to create a new table from an existing one in SQL Server we can do the following

```
SELECT * into Table2
from Table1
WHERE 1=2
```

Whats the point of where clause? I tried it without the where clause and it ran fine. I've seen this where clause in many examples on internet but not the reason why it is required.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The reason you put the `WHERE 1=2` clause in that `SELECT INTO` query is to create a field-copy of the existing table with **no data**.

If you did this:

```
select *
into Table2
from Table1
```

`Table2` would be an exact duplicate of `Table1`, including the data rows.  But if you don't want the data contained in `Table1`, and you just want the table structure, you put a `WHERE` clause to filter out all of the data.

[BOL `SELECT INTO` Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) quote:

> SELECT…INTO creates a new table in the default filegroup and **inserts the resulting rows from the query into it.**

If your `WHERE` clause has no resulting rows, none will be inserted into the new table:  Therefore, you end up with the duplicate schema of the original table with no data (which would be the desired result in this case).

The same effect can be achieved with `TOP (0)`, for example:

```
select top (0) *
into Table2
from Table1;
```

**Note**:  The `SELECT INTO` will not duplicate the source table's indexes, constraints, triggers, or partition schema.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe someone can fine tune my answer here, but in general, when you `select...into #tmptbl` you are locking up the tempdb. If your query is expensive (i.e. takes a long time) this can have negative effects on other processes in the database. To alleviate this, setting your filter as `where 1=2` will make the table instantly, and then you can do an `INSERT INTO #tmptbl` with your actual filter. That way the `tempdb`, which is needed for other processes, can be freed up during your long-running query.

One downside is that in this quick table create, it will only look at the top few rows to determine the data type for each field, so in other words if the first few values of a `varchar` field are less than 20 characters, it will be set as `varchar(20)`, regardless of whether there is a longer value in the full query, which will then give you a **string value would be truncated** error during your insert

Comment: an explanation of why this was downvoted would be helpful